# A proportion about probability and prime numbers

Tags: probability, prime-numbers

A few days ago, in one of the books related to discrete mathematics, I saw a problem with the following form. I thought a lot about this question and asked college professors, but I did not get an answer. The problem is:

**If we choose $m$ numbers from prime numbers that have $n$ digits, what is the probability that they contain $k$ digits of $1$?
What conditions are necessary for the problem to be answered?**

I found some information about counting prime numbers, such as ${\displaystyle \pi (x)\sim {\frac {x}{\ln x}}.\!}$
Because I don't have enough knowledge about these topics, I said to myself that maybe someone from this community can guide me.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: It is a proportion not a probability.  You can guess the proportion for large $n$ and $k \lt n$ (e..g. first digit $1$ slightly more likely than a larger first digit in a quantifiable way, last digit odd if $n>1$) and make reasonable assumptions for the intermediate digits such as a binomial distribution.  The proportion will either be tiny or $0$ for $k=n$ ([repunit primes](https://oeis.org/A004022))

Comment: The prime number theorem won't help , in particular not with this awful approximation. There won't be a nice formula for this problem. You will have to simulate it with random primes and just count the ones.